# ESP32 with CCS811: i2cCheckLineState(): invalid state sda(21)=1, scl(22)=1

Tags: i2c, esp32

I’m having issues with connecting to CCS811 CO2 sensor using Heltec Automation WiFi Kit Masterhawk ESP32. I am using PlatformIO in Arduino mode to build and flash the code.

Here’s what my wiring looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXxqrH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's gist for i2c scanner: https://gist.github.com/sgzmd/9a31350816d173f73df095bdde610ba6

When I run this code on MCU with `build_flags = -D CORE_DEBUG_LEVEL=5` I get:

```
[V][esp32-hal-i2c.c:1486] i2cInit(): num=0 sda=21 scl=22 freq=0
[V][esp32-hal-i2c.c:1682] i2cSetFrequency(): freq=100000Hz
[V][esp32-hal-i2c.c:1698] i2cSetFrequency(): cpu Freq=240Mhz, i2c Freq=100000Hz
[V][esp32-hal-i2c.c:1706] i2cSetFrequency(): Fifo delta=1
[W][esp32-hal-i2c.c:1413] i2cCheckLineState(): invalid state sda(21)=1, scl(22)=1
[D][esp32-hal-i2c.c:1421] i2cCheckLineState(): Recovered after 1 Cycles
Scanning I2C Addresses
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..
```

In the end, nothing is found.

The truly interesting line here is

`[W][esp32-hal-i2c.c:1413] i2cCheckLineState(): invalid state sda(21)=1, scl(22)=`

If I change resistors to 3.3K or 2.2K, nothing changes. When I get rid of pull-up resistors, it changes to `sda(21)=0, scl(22)=0`. At this point I tried:

- Changing CCS811 sensor, to no benefit
- Changing resistors
- Using esp-idf rather than Arduino bootloader
- Changing ESP32 to a different one: JZK ESP-32S ESP32 Development Board
- Following the steps [here]: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/3079.

I must note that when I connect circuit to my Arduino Uno / Pro Mini everything works pretty much as expected, device can be found and I can communicate with it. I'm at my wit end. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: As per the datasheet, "Please be aware that the CCS811 datasheet recommends a burn-in of 48 hours and a run-in of 20 minutes (you must allow 20 minutes for the sensor to warm up and output valid data)." I also see pin 21 is shared "Vext control". Is pin 21 default setting disabled? In addition, the wiring diagram for this CO2 module does not require to pull up resistors, where did you get your schematic from?